# How to check NULL in if condtion?

Tags: java, if-statement

I don't want to use try block to catch the exception I just want to check null with if condition.when i try that it is giving me the null pointer exception.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String name=null;
       if(name.equals(null)){
          System.out.println("null");
       }
       System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: `equals()` is a method belonging to an object. Since you don't have an object (the reference is null) you cannot call the method, and when you try to do that, you get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're calling `name.equals(something)`, which requires name to be non-null.

Just use `name == null` instead.